# Using vector data types in OpenCL structs causes Watch problems in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opencl

Consider the following OpenCL example

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  float value;

  // Causes wrong memory alignment
  int2 position;
} MyStruct;


__kernel void foo()
{
   MyStruct structs[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      int2 pos = { i, i };
      MyStruct newStruct = { i * i, pos };
      structs[i] = newStruct;
   }
}
```

When I use vector data types, like int2 in OpenCL struct, I got memory corruption after adding items(structs) to an array. The members of the next item are overwritten by strange values (I assume memory padding).

In the screenshot below you can see the debug values after the first iteration of the loop. In red are all changed values. Adding the first struct item to the array, causes changes to the value member of the second item.

[image: Iteration 1]

At the second iteration the value of the third item is set to an 'unknown' value. However, the position value of the second item is also wrong.

[image: Iteration 2]

Can someone explain this strange behavior? However, when I replace the **int2** member with two int members, everything works as expected. For me it seems like wrong memory alignment of vector data types.

EDIT

The code is running on Intel CPU, with the latest Intel SDK installed. Running OpenCL code on CPU device was the only possibility to debug kernels by setting break-points. IDE is Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with Intel plugin for OpenCL.

SOLVED

It seems to be a **bug** in Watch window of Visual Studio. It shows wrong values  when debugging struct with vector data type members in OpenCL kernels.

Comment: How is this line not rejected by the OpenCL compiler: int pos = { i, i };

Comment: @LuboAntonov It is really funny. First I tought I copied the wrong code sample, but after checking my sample project, it was int pos. And no compiler error :)

Comment: Compiler issues the warning but value is assigned correctly anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've verified your code on my GPU and it's working with no problem.

Things for you to do/check:

1.Make sure you have the latest OpenCL driver and Graphics driver installed.

2.Make sure that this is not a "Watch" problem. Copy the data to CPU and check. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

a_np = np.zeros(10).astype(np.float32)
b_np = np.zeros(20).astype(np.int32)

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

mf = cl.mem_flags
a_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a_np)
b_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b_np)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  float value;

  // Causes wrong memory alignment
  int2 position;
} MyStruct;

__kernel void foo(
    __global float *a_g, __global int *b_g)
{
   MyStruct structs[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      int pos = { i, i };
      MyStruct newStruct = { i * i, pos };
      structs[i] = newStruct;
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      a_g[i] = structs[i].value;
      b_g[2*i] = structs[i].position.x;
      b_g[2*i+1] = structs[i].position.y;
   }
}
""").build()

prg.foo(queue, (1,1), (1,1), a_g, b_g)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_np, a_g)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, b_np, b_g)

print a_np
print b_np
```

Output:

```
[  0.   1.   4.   9.  16.  25.  36.  49.  64.  81.]
[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9]
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. The values were correctly displayed on the host. Also it seems to be a Watch problem of Visual Studio when trying to display vector data types.

Answer (score 1):

It must be an alignment issue. Depending on device and host, it may or may not work so you need to make sure alignment is explicity compatible on both host and device sides.

If you can watch result, it is already copied to RAM. When copying the result to RAM, you should be sure to use right alignment. `in2` has 8 bytes alignment while two ints have 4 bytes alignment each. First item(`value`) is also 4 bytes.

In opencl device, you are free to use whatever order of fields in a struct, but if you are going to use it on RAM, you need to have compatibility on both sides. This compatibility is generaly achieved some simple edits in structs. Ordering fields by their alignment is one of them. Example:

- Ordering of alignment sizes from biggest to smallest (biggest first). Because hardware uses special memory operation optimizations to read a struct fast, which makes it not known on RAM. Only device knows it, unless you explicity order fields. Example:

(struct)

```
int2 var0;  // biggest alignment (8)
float var1; // smallest alignment (4)

another example:  

int4 var0;
float4 var1;
int2 var2;
int2 var3;
int2 var4;
char var5;  // 57 bytes total
char dummy1; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy2; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy3; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy4; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy5; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy6; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
char dummy7; // to have struct size equal to power of 2.
```

Comment: I tried to swap the variable definition, but the values were still wrongly displayed. As @doqtor suggested, It was a Watch problem of Visual Studio. The values are correctly dislayed on the host.

Comment: Are you using an addon to watch gpu buffer?

Comment: No, I am using the standard Watch window of Visual Studio. It could be intercepted by the Intel OpenCL debugger plug-in for VS when debugging kernels. I am not sure. Please note that the kernel is running on the CPU in order the debugger to stop on break-points in the kernel. Furthermore, I inspect the values of the local array and not the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation about memory alignment. It helped me better understand the concept.

Comment: The dummy array part was wrong I think, I changed it to fields